# JPA query calling getters millions of times

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I've been profiling my code to try to understand what the bottleneck is and have come across some rather odd behaviour when running a db query and I just can't explain it:

To set the scene:

```
class Edge {
    int from;
    int to;
}

class Foo {
    ... //50 attributes
}

class Bar {
    ... //50 attributes
}

class EdgeDAO extends JpaDaoSupport {
    List<Edge> getEdgesFrom(int from) {
        Map<String, Integer> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.add("from", from);
        return getJpaTemplate().findByNamedParams("from Edge where from=:from, params);
    }
}
```

When profiling I call the DAO method `getEdgesFrom(int)` 246 times.

The bit that I can't explain is that JProfiler reports the in the 246 invocations of `getEdgesFrom(int)`, each of the 50 getters on `Foo` and `Bar` are called 4,820,124 times. `Foo` and `Bar` aren't even in the `Edge` object.

Can anyone help me understand why this might be?

Comment: Try to debug and to see the queries made (an eventually detecting the place that triggers that, by debugging step by step). No one told that the getters of Foo and Bar instances are called from this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the `FlushMode` set to `AUTO`. Changing this value to `COMMIT` resolved the problem